# Fatal error: Switch statements may only contain one default clause in mpdf.php

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mPDF and it is working fine with localhost. I upload the project to live server and it is not generating pdf correctly.

```
<?php

// HTML ommited

$body = ob_get_clean();

include ("mpdf/mpdf.php");

$mpdf = new mPDF('+aCJK', 'A4', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($body);

$mpdf->Output('SaveToPDF.pdf', 'D');
```

On the top, I put the error show code. To see the error what is going wrong I have the following error.

> Fatal error: Switch statements may only contain one default clause in
>   /customers/d/e/a/....URL..GO..HERE/mpdf.php on line 1432

I am using  PHP Version 5.6.31 on my Localhost and on live I am using one.com and there I can switch to different PHP versions, and I tried all. i.e. 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 beta

> I am using mPDF 5.7 and it is not composer version. I wanted to use
>   chines character for my pdf and it good support available in 5.7.
>   That's why I chose older version

Comment: What php versions are on your live server and on your localhost?

Comment: On my server, I had PHP Version 7.1 Localhost PHP Version 5.6.31

Comment: Also, are you using the latest mpdf composer package? Tell please the exact mpdf version you are using.

Comment: I am using mPDF 5.7 and it is not composer version. I wanted to use chines character for my pdf and it good support available in 5.7. That's why I chose older version

Comment: Thank you, Ivan, I am editing my question also to make it more easy to understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old `mpdf` versions don't support PHP7, unfortunately ([mpdf issue)](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/277). You can either:

1. Switch to actual mpdf version and use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036954/how-to-use-mpdf-for-chinese-language) for chinese fonts;
2. Or change your live server PHP to 5.6 ([PHP RFC multiple default cases syntax error](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/switch.default.multiple));
3. Or fix this switch issue in `mpdf` source yourself (people discussed the possible solution [in this hhvm issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/3822#issuecomment-56472838)), you just need to remove one of the `default` statements.

Comment: I deleted this one and still had the same issue.. case 'A4': default: {$format = array(595.28,841.89); break;}

Comment: I worked on it that you suggested for chines and I am using old version

Comment: There is and never will be a PHP 5.7 version?

Comment: @JanSlabon, of course there is no PHP 5.7 version, it's a typo, I mean PHP 7. Thank you for pointing, I'll edit an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Older post but this may help someone, I had the same issue moving a site from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7, I have found an updated version of MPDF which works fine for me at https://github.com/kbs1/mpdf-5.7-php7

Answer (score 0):

If you have migrated from php5 to php7 then you can use the below patch in your mpdf.php file.

https://github.com/franzliedke/wp-mpdf/commit/9dc489215fbd1adcb514810653a73dea71db8e99

Download the raw file from the above URL and upload it to your directory. For me it worked perfectly.