# mpdf not supporting chinese fonts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mpdf

I am using mpdf. When I try to write chinese words to the WriteHtml(), the resulting pdf containing square boxes instead of those fonts.

```
require 'mpdf/mpdf.php';
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = false;
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
$pdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8']); 
$mpdf->SetHeader('|<h2>Booking Invoice</h2>|');
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}'); 
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;    
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
 ob_start();

 include "test.php";
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

i tried mpdf 6.0 and above version, but still same result

Please advice

Thank you.

Comment: Is that works for You? Why are You doing `$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = false;` before instantiate the `$mpdf` object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mPDF for Chinese Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036954/how-to-use-mpdf-for-chinese-language)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036954/how-to-use-mpdf-for-chinese-language also got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it, please check this if u have same error

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

            $mpdf=new \mPDF('+aCJK','A4','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);
            $mpdf->SetHeader('|Booking Invoice|');
    $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}'); 
            ob_start();
            include('cis.php');

          $html = ob_get_contents();
            ?>


            <?php
            $html = ob_get_clean();


            $html = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $html);
            $html = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $html);



            $mpdf->SetAutoFont();
            $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
            $mpdf->autoLangToFont   = true;



            $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

```
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
```

Comment: Also can't, same square boxes only appear , please help me for this

Comment: Have You tried different conversion format? Docs says about 10 different formats for chinese:
`EUC-CN, HZ, GBK, GB18030, EUC-TW, BIG5, CP950, BIG5-HKSCS, ISO-2022-CN, ISO-2022-CN-EXT`

Comment: i don't know how, please let me know how to do that

Comment: Try this as I pasted You in the answer, but with one of these formats. And paste it after `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(); `.

Comment: include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';

$mpdf->SetHeader('|<h2>Booking Invoice</h2>|');
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');// Giving page number to your footer.

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// Buffer the following html with PHP so we can store it to a variable later
ob_start();
?>
<?php include "invoice.php";
 //This is your php page ?>
<?php 
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
// send the captured HTML from the output buffer to the mPDF class for processing
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

Comment: I attached code above but still same square boxes only appear, i am using MPDF 6.0

Please help me for this

Comment: on what kind of system did you VIEW your pdf file? Was it Adobe's reader, or another program? Did you also try to experiment with the option to subset Chinese fonts when saving the pdf? Furthermore, is the output of your included `cis.php` or `test.php` well formatted and in the same encoding (utf-8)?

Answer (score 0):

Use **mode** on object creation

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8']);
```

and write your utf-8 content to it