# Default Japanese font used in mPDF

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf

I'm using mPDF 6.0 to create PDF files in Japanese.

The font can be set as "the free Adobe CJK Asian fonts" setting useAdobeCJK to true, like this:

```
$mpdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
```

In that case, what is the font actually used?

I've looked everywhere and I couldn't find it. File config_lang2fonts.php shows that Setting useAdobeCJK to true uses a font called as "sjis", but I can't figure out what it is. The answer is not in mPDF documentation or on Adobe website.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to get the font so I can use it in other parts of my program, for example to create a Word document with the same font.

Comment: as I remember all my troubles with mPDF - it is always about the encoding:) - try the answer from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975788/mpdf-not-supporting-chinese-fonts

Comment: Thanks @myxaxa but I don't have an encoding problem. I can create my PDF without problem. I need to know what font is used.