# How to use mPDF for Chinese Language - Chinese language is not supporting

Tags: mpdf

I am using mPDF to save form input data to PDF. For English, it is working fine. But when i translate the content in chinese language and after that when i hit the mpdf function then it prints unwanted symbols instead of chinese strings.

Need help

```
$config = [
    'mode' => '+aCJK', 
    // "allowCJKoverflow" => true, 
    "autoScriptToLang" => true,
    // "allow_charset_conversion" => false,
    "autoLangToFont" => true,
];
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
```

i tried this too but it's not working.
Also tried this [How to use mPDF for Chinese Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036954/how-to-use-mpdf-for-chinese-language)

and this solutions

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/discussions/1488

Comment: Your example code is not sufficient, update it to be reproducible. What does "not working" mean?